# How can I layout GridView.count so the widgets start building from the top of the parent widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, layout

When I build a GridView.count - it centers the children widgets, how do I get them to start building from the very center top of their parent in Flutter?

I can't find the appropriate property to do this. I tried wrapping the Gridview.count in an Align widget aligning to topCenter and that didnt work either.

(example pic attached).

Thank you!

[image]

```
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.greenAccent,
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: GridView.count(
                          childAspectRatio: 1.5,
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.orange,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.purple,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Have you tried setting shrinkWrap = true? I can't replicate your problem as it involves either Row or Column

Comment: The widget you posted already is positioned from the top of a parent. Show parent widget and we will aid you.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply! Yes it was something wrong in my parent widget tree was causing the issue, ive tried both answers here and it is now fixed. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to point that its not about widget you posted:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 140,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: GridView.count(
                    childAspectRatio: 1.5,
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.purple,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something else in the parent widget tree. Check https://dartpad.dev/735baabeb592535b2c272a05e0e24344?null_safety=true

it is aligned to top

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Container(
                      color: Colors.greenAccent,
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: GridView.count(
                          childAspectRatio: 1.5,
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.orange,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.purple,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ;
  }
}
```